# How do I run my React Native application on my device rather than in IPhone 6 simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have been reading React Native's documentation as well as forums, and answers to similar questions but cannot figure out how to run my application on my device.

I have tried what was mentioned in this question "[Run react-native application on iOS device directly from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495793/run-react-native-application-on-ios-device-directly-from-command-line)", as well as deleting the build folder from the ios directory and rerunning the script. I will run this command `npm run ios --device "Anthony’s iPhone"`, but it results in this `Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 11.3)...` I have also tried running `npm run ios --simulator "iPhone 5s"` but again I get `Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 11.3)...`. I am not sure where to go from here, more information can be seen below. Of course, the simulator is always launched and functions properly but I would like to control whether it runs on a device or in which simulator.

```
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:fitness-app anthonysette$ npm run ios --device "Anthony’s iPhone"

> FitnessApp@0.1.0 ios /Users/anthonysette/Documents/fitness-app
> react-native run-ios "Anthony’s iPhone"

Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/anthonysette/Documents/fitness-app/node_modules (15ms)
Found Xcode workspace FitnessApp.xcworkspace
Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 11.3)...
Building using "xcodebuild -workspace FitnessApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme FitnessApp -destination id=28DE4434-4D1A-4B5E-8C16-0AC2C101F8E0 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:
```

**Edit: Added info from package.json**

My package.json has a portion called scripts which contains the following

```
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "rename": "node ./bin/rename.js",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Comment: Can you also try this `react-native run-ios --device`?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Just tried that, but for me `npm run ios` runs `react-native run-ios`. The results of that command was `Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:fitness-app anthonysette$ react-native run-ios --device
bash: react-native: command not found`

Comment: Check my edit, added some info on the package.json file in my project.

Comment: You can either install `react-native cli` globally or add a script to your package.json as `"ios-device": "react-native run-ios --device"` and run `npm run ios-device`

Comment: @PritishVaidya That worked!!! I now get this `Could not find device with the name: "true".
Choose one of the following:
Anthony’s iPhone Udid: __UID__
Anthony’s MacBook Pro Udid: __UID__
Anthonys-MacBook-Pro:fitness-app anthonysette$`, how do I choose? Also if you would like to submit that as an answer I would be happy to mark it as answered for other people to see!

Comment: I think this is working `npm run ios-device "Anthony’s iPhone"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `npm run ios` as defined your script will run `react-native run-ios`.
Therefore you can either install `react-native cli` globally and use

```
react-native run-ios --device "Anthony’s iPhone"
```

or add a new script to your `package.json` as

```
"ios-device": "react-native run-ios --device"
```

and run `npm run ios-device "Anthony’s iPhone"`

Comment: How do you get the name of the device?

Comment: @Sam ... `xcrun xctrace list devices`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to install "**create-react-native-app**" to create react native app. You can run your app in your device through "**expo**". Run your app with "**npm start**" command. Download and install expo in your phone and scan the generated QR code. It also supports hot reload.

Note - Make sure your computer and phone are on same network.

Comment: I had previously done this and in most cases, it would work but after ejecting, or starting with the starter kit from `react-native-firebase` (already ejected) you cannot run the application through expo. (As far as I am aware, I could be wrong)