# React Native Can't build iOS device from command line

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-code

In order to build react native on iOS, I used the following command on the command line (VSCode) and  I've tried to use the following command on the command line (VSCode) to build react native iOS and it doesn't work.

```
react-native run-ios --device "device name"
```

The application is installed successfully, but it is not reflected in the actual device.

```
info Installing and launching your app on "iPhone"
success Installed the app on the device.
```

I did this site as well as referring to it, but it didn't work.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495793/run-react-native-application-on-ios-device-directly-from-command-line]

I'd like to implement an iOS actual device build with VScode.
If you know of a similar situation or how to deal with it, please let me know.

[Version information]

react-native: 0.61.5

VSCode 1.51.0

Xcode 12.1

iOS 14.1